# Facebook Stories Translation

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story

When I translate tickers and stories in the translation app on Facebook I need to follow the structure there - for example:

```
{name1} put down {initial meld1} on {Rummikub}.
```

But after I translated the sentence, Facebook puts in the place of `{initial meld1}` text in English and not translated text. How can I translate this text as well?